# SIGABRT error due to getline(cin,s)

Tags: c++, getline, sigabrt

This code works fine on my pc but showing SIGABRT on online judge(Spoj).why? i think problem is with getline it got accepted when i used:

```
input format: 52 + 81 = machula or 5machula + 81 = 133

string s1,s2,s3;
cin>>s1;
cin.ignore(3);
cin>>s2;
cin.ignore(3);
cin>>s3;
```

but i want to use substr earlier which need me to use getline

```
string s,s1,s2,s3;
//cin.ignore(INT_MAX,'\n');
getline(cin,s);
int p1=0,p2,p3,l1,l2,l3;
l1=s.find("+")-1;
p2=s.find("+")+2;
l2=s.find("=")-s.find("+")-3;
p3=s.find("=")+2;
l3=s.length()-s.find("=")-2;
s1=s.substr(p1,l1);
s2=s.substr(p2,l2);
s3=s.substr(p3,l3);
```

Comment: You should probably check if `find()` found something valid, before proceeding.

Comment: Think about what's more likely: There is some unidentified bug with `std::getline`, and/or `std::string`, which were thoroughly tested (by usage) by most of the developers in the world, or your expectations of what it does doesn't match the reality (or, possibly, there is some UB in your code)? Please provide [mcve] (including used inputs to reproduce the issue).

Comment: You should **always** verify whether input was successful *after* trying to read the value and *before* using the result.

Comment: input was successful and works fine for every testcases i tried but still every time i submit code having getline it showing SIGABRT but code with cinn got accepted

Comment: Did you check if there are some trailing newline? https://ideone.com/wc52Zt

Comment: @Bob__ `getline()` doesn't include the trailing newline, you're thinking of `fgets()`.

Comment: @Barmar Yes. But it consumes it.

Comment: @Bob__ So? Where in his code does he expect `s` to contain the newline?

Comment: Your code would be more understandable if you called `s.find("+")` and `s.find("=")` just once and put them in variables.

Comment: You should check whether `s.find()` actually found anything. Maybe the online judge provides invalid input and you're not checking for them returning `string::npos`.

Comment: @Barmar. http://www.spoj.com/problems/ABSYS/ "The first line of the input file contains an integer T specifying the number of test cases.". My educated guess is that there is a `cin` somewhere in the *not shown* code that leaves a trailing newline from the *not shown* real input. Actually, next to that they say "Each test case is preceded by a blank line."

Comment: @Bob__ Good find. I guess that may be what the commented-out line was supposed to be for.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/v0pCG0rt " I used `cin.ignore(INT_MAX,'\n')` after getting input for testcases through cin to ignore trailing newline. Link contain my complete code if you wanna check"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input specification of the [problem the OP are trying to solve](http://www.spoj.com/problems/ABSYS/) states:

> The first line of the input file contains an integer T specifying the number of test cases. Each test case is preceded by a blank line.

OP attempt to deal with it can be summarized as:

```
int t;
cin >> t;
cin.ignore(INT_MAX,'\n');
for(int u=0; u<t; u++)
{
    // ...
    std::string s;
    // cin.ignore(INT_MAX,'\n'); <-- another attempt
    getline(cin, s);
    // ... various operations involving s
}
```

The problem with this approach is that, while the first `ignore` consume the trailing newline left in the stream buffer by `cin >> t;`, all the other empty lines (lines consisting of only a newline) read by `getline` result in empty strings and the following code can't handle such strings.

For example, when `std::basic_string::find` can't find the passed substring, it returns `std::basic_string::npos`, which is defined as

```
static const size_type npos = -1;
```

So `p2` ends up to be `1` and the call `s.substr(p2,l2);` throws an `std::out_of_range` exception, because we are trying to extract a substring from a zero sized string, starting from position 1.

Adding the commented-out `ignore` line could solve the issue, but It may be better to rewrite the whole loop:

```
int t;
std::cin >> t;

int u = 0;
while ( u < t )
{
    // ...
    std::string s;
    getline(cin, s);
    if ( s.empty() )
        continue;
    // ... various operations involving s
    ++u;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you helped me a lot i appreciate your effort of going through my trash code. Online definitions of SIGABRT were going out of mind.